# $message is undefined on laravel 8

Tags: laravel, undefined

I'm learning Laravel, and I've been trying to pass data between a controller and a view, but I'm still getting the same error on the page. Does anyone know how to fix this? Even with this small code, it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to make a configuration or something?

I've tried

```
->with('message', 'Hi Victoria')
```

`view`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>App title</title>
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Hello, {{ $message }}</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
</html>
```

`controller`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Hello;

class HelloWorld extends Controller
{
    public function sayHello()
    {
  
        return view('hello', ['message' => 'Hi Victoria']);
    
    }
}
```

`web.php`

```
Route::get('/', function(){

    return view('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have written a controller, but you are not using it. In your route ( web.php ), you have returned the view.

You should take a look at [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#basic-controllers) regarding how to make a route point to a controller method

So, you would need to change your route in `web.php` to

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\HelloWorld;

Route::get('/', [HelloWorld::class, 'sayHello']);
```

Answer (score 1):

In `web.php`, you should write the following code to use the `HelloWorld` controller:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\HelloWorld;

Route::get('/', [HelloWorld::class, 'sayHello']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in web.php

```
Route::get('/', function(){

    return view('hello',['message' => 'Hi Victoria']);
});
```